ClickOnce no admite el nivel de ejecución de solicitudes 'requireAdministrator'
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error       ClickOnce no admite el nivel de ejecución de solicitudes 'requireAdministrator'.    wfaSadReportes
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <!-- Opciones del manifiesto UAC
           Si quiere cambiar el nivel del Control de cuentas de usuario de Windows reemplace el 
           nodo requestedExecutionLevel por uno de los siguientes.

      <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

          Especificar el elemento requestedExecutionLevel deshabilitará la virtualización de archivos y registros. 
          Quite este elemento si la aplicación necesita esta virtualización para la compatibilidad
          con versiones anteriores.
      -->
      <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      <!-- <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />-->
    </requestedPrivileges>
    <applicationRequestMinimum>
      <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
      <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" Unrestricted="true" />
    </applicationRequestMinimum>
  </security>
</trustInfo>

